# Suggestions for string lookup optimizations

Tags: mysql, django, algorithm, lookup, backend

We have the below MySQL database table with about 75,000 entries. Each entry in the table represents a symbol in the system for which further data could be retrieved. This table is queried for autocomplete purposes - a user looks up a symbol, which is then matched to either the symbol's name or to its tags (semicolon separated list of strings). When the user selects the correct symbol, relevant data is fetched. Here is the table's description:

```
CREATE TABLE `symbols` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,  
  `tags` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `type` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') NOT NULL,  
  `popularity` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_symbol_name` (`type`,`symbol`),  
  KEY `symbol_idx` (`symbol`),  
  KEY `type_popularity_idx` (`type`,`popularity`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The above table is stored, alongside copious amounts of data, on a backend machine which serves this data over a JSON API. Currently, our frontend JavaScript code is querying the backend server directly in AJAX in order to do the autocomplete. Instead, to speed things up, we want to create a local cached version of the symbols table on the server from which the frontend is served (the frontend is written in django). This is possible since the table contains under 100,000 symbols, and because the table only gets updated about once an minute. Furthermore, it will allow us to implement better matching algorithms like Levenshtein distance.

How would you go about creating this type of cached symbol table? Obviously the lookup will have to happen in code (probably Python), but how would you store the data, and how would you sync it once a minute? We have a Redis server running on the django frontend server, but that introduces the question of persistence... Any thoughts are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple hash table, together with a "last updated time". Every time you do a lookup in the hash, check the "last updated" time. If it is more than a minute in the past, dump the data in the hash and reload it from the DB. Of course you have to make sure to avoid race conditions...

There are other alternatives but this is the simplest way and will be easiest to code correctly. If you find that hitting one of your transactions per minute with the extra latency of a big DB operation is not acceptable, you can come up with something a bit more complicated (such as running the DB operations asynchronously, on a background thread). To prepare for that eventuality, encapsulate this code in a class. (Then if it's too slow, you can play with the implementation without affecting any of your other code.)

Of course, there are other things you could do if you need more performance. You could add an `updated_time` column to your DB records, and then only load the ones which have been updated since last time. Will this actually make things faster? If it does, will the difference be big  to enough to even matter? There's no way to know unless you try it out. That's why it's better to try the simpler solution first, and see if it reaches your performance goals.

Comment: could you please expand on this idea? I can't really see how that makes anything faster, especially if every minute a request to the DB might be made prior returning a result?

Comment: Say you are handling 1000 requests a minute. For 999 of those, you can just do a simple in-memory hash lookup without hitting the DB. A simple hash lookup with a string key should take something on the order of microseconds. For #1000, you will have to hit the DB to reload all the data. If adding that overhead to 1/1000 of your requests is unacceptable, you can run those DB operations on a background thread. What I'm proposing here will be easier to code correctly, though. You can migrate to the more complicated solution if this one doesn't meet your performance goals.